# How to replicate ArcGIS geometric intervals in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, classification

Is it possible to replicate ArcGIS's Geometric Intervals in QGIS 3 layers symbology?

I am using QGIS 3.10.9 LTS and would like to assign a geometric interval style to a simple shapefile of UK counties which contains a numeric field. In QGIS-layers-symbology one can select 'graduated' as the style and select the numeric field as 'value', but none of the six modes QGIS provides is appropriate to my analysis: What I need is a Geometric Interval classification like the one available in ArcGIS. I cannot see a Plugin that attempts to address this and the one online article I can find is from 2014 and uses an experimental Python script on a now unavailable website. Is there a way of solving this task? My knowledge of Python is very limited.

Comment: For those of us who don't have access to Arc can you explain what a Geometrical interval is?

Comment: Geometric intervals just form a series by multiplying a seed value by a constant factor. I reverse engineered it in 20 minutes four years ago, but don't have access to that code at the moment.

Comment: This sure sounds like a useful plugin!

Comment: It's not a plugin, just some math to generate the series I wanted as a custom interval in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, at best, but it's too much code for a comment.

To reverse-engineer a geometric distribution algorithm into a custom distribution that I could use to control the exact symbology I wanted on a range of data, I generated this function (which is more bound to three-place data than I'd like):

```py
import math

def computeRamp(max,bins):
    vals = [ 0 ]
    labs = []
    cmax = math.floor((max + 0.001)*1000)/1000
    a1   = pow(cmax,1.0/(bins-1))

    digits = int(math.ceil(math.log(cmax,10))) + 4
    labLayout = "{:@n.3f} - {:@n.3f}".replace('@n',str(digits))

    lo = 0.0
    hi = a1 / 4.0
    vals.append(hi)
    labs.append(labFormat.format(lo,hi-0.001))

    lo = 0.0
    hi = a1
    vals.append(hi)
    labs.append(labFormat.format(lo,hi-0.001))

    for i in range(2,bins):
        lo = hi
        hi = lo * a1
        vals.append(hi)
        labs.append(labFormat.format(lo,hi-0.001))

    return vals,labs

vals,labs = computeRamp(1234.567,6)
for i in range(len(labs)):
    print("{:.3f}\n    {:s}".format(vals[i],labs[i]))
print("{:.3f}".format(vals[-1]))
```

Which results in the distribution:

```
0.000
       0.000 -    1.037
1.038
       1.038 -    4.151
4.152
       4.152 -   17.242
17.243
      17.243 -   71.598
71.599
      71.599 -  297.311
297.312
     297.312 - 1234.567
1234.568
```

I cheat by taking a quarter of the first cell value from the a true geometric progression (which would use `pow(cmax,1.0/bins)`, but I found this made better maps).

How you apply this to QGIS is left as an exercise.